# Open Dialog Box when Notification is Clicked (FCM)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display the title and message text in dialog box when the notification is clicked. Here is my code with `onMessageReceived` and SendNotification, I am using fcm from console to send the message-

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}


private void sendNotification (String messageBody){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this ,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    Uri defaultsoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Guru Nanak Dev Polytechnic College");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultsoundUri);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a activity reference to show dialog so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this ,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fromNotification",true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

In MainActivity:

```
Intent intent= getIntent;
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("fromNotification",true))
        {
            // show your dialog here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PendingIntent to MainActivity send messageBody as `EXTRA` i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this ,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", messageBody);
```

Now, when a user clicks on the notification, it will take them to MainActivity. In `onCreate()` of MainActivity check whether this activity is opened from notification or somewhere else (with the help of getIntent) like:

```
String notificationData = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");

//if this activity is opened from notification, it will have extra data
if(notificationData !=null){

 //now open dialog
 showDialog(notificationData);
}
```

Comment: it doesnt displays the dialog box still when opened from notification  [https://imgur.com/a/L814Mz7] you can see my main activity and firebasemessage service

Comment: It seems okay, just put `super.onCreate()` in the start of `onCreate()`

Comment: not necessarily. just make sure that notificationData isn't null when user clicks on the notification. you can check it by debugging the app or showing logs for notificationData